# manipulate a sequence of random variable into almost sure convergence to 0

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Show that there exist a sequnce $c_n$ of positive real numbers such that $\frac{X_n}{C_n}$ that converge to 0 almost surely.

So far, I consider the sequence $c_n$ to be some function of the expected values of $X_n$.

Comment: Your idea is not so great, since you cannot assume that the $X_n$ even *have* expected values (i.e. that they are integrable).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for any numbers $\epsilon_n, \delta_n > 0$, show that you can find $C_n$ sufficiently large that $$P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{C_n}\right| \ge \delta_n\right) < \epsilon_n.$$
Now decide how to choose $\epsilon_n, \delta_n$, thinking about the Borel-Cantelli lemma.